# Why does Java 2D array initialization go against intuition?

Tags: java, arrays

Why do multidimensional arrays behave opposite from what you would expect when creating them? An `int[][]` array means that I should have an array of arrays of ints. I would read it backwards starting from the rightmost brackets: `((int)[])[]`.

And I would expect the following code,

```
int[][] grid = new int[][3];
// ...Proceed to fill nested arrays
```

to create a 3-element array of int arrays. But it produces a compiler error. However this,

```
int[][] grid = new int[3][];
```

does not. The first example makes sense to me, because it seems like I am creating a 3-element array of null int array references. But the second example doesn't make sense to me, since it seems as though the actual array of int arrays has no set size, but the 'nested' arrays are still initialized with a size of 3. Why is this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking why it doesn't make sense which none of us can answer other than to say your interpretation of the syntax isn't what you get. It makes sense to me ;)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils  Then explain why it makes sense to you please.

Comment: Because the designers didn't use your intuition. They used their own. The question here is really why you have the intuition you have, and only you can answer that.

Comment: *An `int[][]` array means that I should have an array of arrays of ints.* **Correct**! It does. *I would read it backwards starting from the rightmost brackets* No. Java arrays are an **`Object` type**. You read it left to right, it evaluates left to right.

Comment: @EJP The way you initialize 2D arrays using `new` in C++ like the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) is what gives me that intuition.

Comment: I look at it like declared dimensions. The last dimension is the only one that does *not* have to have a size; all others do since arrays are fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is reversed.  The declaration

```
int [][] a;
```

just creates a variable that's a reference to an array of references to arrays of ints.  An allocation

```
new int [3][2];
```

creates an array of 3 references. Each reference is to an array of 2 elements.  The allocation

```
new int [3][];
```

still makes sense. It still creates an array of 3 references, but the references are `null`.

On the other hand, the allocation

```
new int [][3];
```

doesn't make sense because it doesn't specify how many references are to be allocated.  Knowing how many elements would be in the referenced arrays isn't of any use.

Note that to get at `a[i][j]`, Java uses the `i`th reference to get the address of the corresponding array, then gets the `j`th element within that array.

This is in contrast to C or C++, where a *declaration* (not allocation)

```
int a[][3];
```

is possible. This creates a single pointer (with undefined value) that refers to a single block of memory that's treated as a sequence of rows each having 3 elements.  Here, there are no references.  Elements are accessed with arithmetic: `a[i][j]` is the integer with offset `3*i+j`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking a bit too much in terms of C.

In java, there are no true 2-dimensional arrays.  There are only one-dimensional arrays, and to create a two-dimensional array you have to create a one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays.  (Incidentally, this means that each row can be of different length.  But that's besides the point.)

So when you declare an array in C you have to specify the size of a row, so that the compiler can figure out how far apart in memory each row is.  The number of rows does not really matter as far as the type is concerned, it is a run-time consideration.

But when you declare an array in Java you have to begin by specifying the size of the primary array, (essentially, how many rows you have,) and then allocate each sub-array (each row.)

Edit:

Essentially, `int[][] a = new int[][5]` in java would mean "allocate an array of `int[]` of unknown size (impossible) where each `int[]` will contain 5 elements (impossible)".  Instead, you have to say `int[][] a = new int[5][]` which means "allocate an array of 5 pointers to `int[]` and I am going to be allocating each member `int[]` later."

Comment: `int[][] a = { { 0 }, { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6 } };`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is this supposed to be somehow telling me that I wrote something wrong?

Comment: Nope. Just a concrete example for OP of your aside about jagged arrays. Still not sure OP gets it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I understand the concept of jagged arrays, just not why the 'inner' arrays are referenced from the first set of brackets in the array, not the second. It seems like it should be the other way around. None of this is new to me, I'm just having a crisis.

Comment: @name We don't have to use `[]` at all, consider `System.out.println(java.lang.reflect.Array.getInt(java.lang.reflect.Array.get(grid, 0), 0));` which is a really contrived example, but shows that Java really does consider an `int[]` a subtype of `Object` (with all that implies) - so an `int[][]` is also an array of arrays (as is an `int[][][]`).

Answer (score 0):

Your first interpretation is wrong.
When you do `int[][] grid = new int[][3];` it has no meaning but : create 0(or null) arrays of 3 columns it's impossible (You made no memory place for the 3 arrays so you can't declare them).
The second one means : Create 3 arrays pointing to nothing (empty). that's possible since you can append elements later.
I hope this was as simplified as possible so you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

We usually tend to read code from left to right.

A representation like `int[ [] ]` could help because then you see the nesting, however it would not be suitable for those size statements you showed. Thus you need to decide for either your interpretation or the one they choosed.

As I already said, we tend to read from left to right, so when writing `new int[3][];` most people expect that the left brackets represent the **outer-array** and the right the **inner-array**.

Take a look at the equation `(x * (y + z))`, the outer brackets are read before the inner ones.

It kind of reminds me of [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) where you would write `* x (+ y z)` for the above equation.

Comment: _As I already said, we tend to read from left to right, so when writing new int[3][]; most people expect that the left brackets represent the outer-array and the right the inner-array._ And I have never questioned that until now, but it seems backwards.

Comment: You read from left to right. As in the math equation, first comes the outer and then the inner stuff, that is my intuition here.